# batch %%~n1 not returning variable

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg

I have a script for converting video using a batch and ffmpeg. however im confused as to why %%~nf and %%~n1 aren't returning the name of the file (without the format). I've tried various " ' % to see what the cause is, though im quite lost as the %~1 variable works fine.

```
if not %Vcodec% == h264 if not %Acodec% == ac3 (echo Converting Video, Converting Audio
'C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -i "%~1" -map 0 -vcodec libx264 -scodec copy -acodec ac3 -b:a 640K '%%~n1.mkv')
```

Produces

```
C:\Users\Desktop\to fix>if not mpeg4 == h264 if not mp3 == ac3 (
echo Converting Video, Converting Audio
 'C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -i "S02E01.avi" -map 0 -vcodec libx264 -scodec copy -acodec ac3 -b:a 640K %~n1.mkv'
)
```

rather than SO2EO1. if i add another % to it, it returns

```
C:\Users\Desktop\to fix>if not mpeg4 == h264 if not mp3 == ac3 (
echo Converting Video, Converting Audio
 'C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -i "S02E01.avi" -map 0 -vcodec libx264 -scodec copy -acodec ac3 -b:a 640K %S02E01.mkv'
)
```

So i don't understand why one variable works and the other doesn't event though it should? As in [the example](https://gdion.wordpress.com/2016/06/12/simple-dts-to-ac3-using-ffmpeg/) I've used to make this script "%%~nf".mkv works. I'm a novice to scripting, so if you do provide an answer an explanation or a link to an explanation would be great.

Comment: why do you use `%~1`, but `%%~n1`? And why adding even more `%`?

Comment: Doubling the `%`-signs in batch files only applies to [`for` variable references](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html), not to be confused with `%1`, which is an [argument reference](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) (see also [`call`](http://ss64.com/nt/call.html)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

%1 is an internal variable, so

```
'%~n1.mkv'
```

See https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html

> %~n1 Expand %1 to a file Name without file extension C:\utils\MyFile
>   or if only a path is present (with no trailing backslash) - the last
>   folder in that path.